# Check if user has permission in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, replit

I am making a kick command for my discord.py bot. Here is some code that the kick command might be:

```
    async kick_command(self, ctx, userName: discord.User):
      prefix_used = ctx.prefix
      alias_used = ctx.invoked_with
      text = msg[len(prefix_used) + len(alias_used):]
      if discord.User permissions = "admin":
        try:
          kick(User)
        except Exception as e:
          ee = "Error: " + e
          await ctx.send_message(content=ee)
```

I am pretty sure the if statement and `kick(User)` are invalid syntax. Can you help me?

My code:
[click here](https://repl.it/@CodingAndMemes/Moderator-Bot/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
@bot.command()
@has_permissions(kick_members=True)  
async def kick(self, ctx, Member: discord.Member):
          await bot.kick(Member)

@kick.error
async def kick_error(error, ctx):
   if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
       await ctx.send("You don't have permission to do that!")
```

don't forget to import the `has_permissions`: `from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions`

Comment: can you fix?
`NameError: name ‘kick_members’ is not defined`

Comment: @CodingAndMemes i changed the code as this is the easiest way to do it, i believe

Comment: I changed it up a little bit,
I put this:


`async def kick_command(self, ctx, Member: discord.Member):`

`    await kick(Member)`


And it gives me this:
`NameError: name ‘kick’ is not defined`

Comment: probably because you put `kick(Member)` instead of `ctx.kick(Member)`

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a better way of doing this without importing. I would recommend not importing and just doing this the way I am showing below because it will save you some time if you plan to import all of those.

This doesn't require importing anything for has_permissions.

```
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)  
async def kick(self, ctx, Member: discord.Member):
    await bot.kick(Member)
```

Comment: You still need to `from discord.ext import commands`, though.